# How to access the Domain Shared API when the Contacts API will be deprecated in 2021?

Tags: google-shared-contacts

The Google Contact API is considered obsolete as of June 15, 2021. The Domain Shared API uses the Contacts API to edit directory contacts. Will a solution be available to replace the contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts) won't be affected by Contacts API deprecation, and it will still be available for use after June 2021, according to the [deprecation announcement](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement#what%E2%80%99s_changing):

> Please note that **the Domain Shared Contacts API is not affected by these changes**.

#### Reference:

- [Action Required: Legacy Google Contacts API will be shut down on June 15, 2021](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement)